# Removing Event Listener - Do I need to pass the exact same anonymous function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, event-handling, dom-events

```
 componentDidMount() {
    window.addEventListener("scroll", (e) => {console.log("Hello"});
  }

 componentWillUnmount() {
    window.removeEventListener("scroll", (e) => {console.log("Hello"});
  }
```

...do I really need to do `window.removeEventListener("scroll", (e) => {console.log("Hello")});`?

Or can I just do `window.removeEventListener("scroll", ()=> {});` (with an empty function)? I don't understand why, when removing the eventListener, I need to pass it the exact same anonymous function?

what if I do `window.removeEventListener("scroll", ()=> {console.log("Hello2")});` - is this considered a new function now? So will this **not** remove the original event listener (which has `console.log("Hello");`) ?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you have to pass exact same reference, since function is an object and variable holding a reference and  function(){} is not equals function(){}

```
function stuff(){/* your stuff;*/}
window.addEventListener("event",stuff);
window.removeEventListener("event",stuff);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `componentWillUnmount` function will not remove event listener because the function reference of the event listener which was attached in `componentDidMount` is not the same as the one it(compWillUnmount) is trying to remove.

You can check it out by creating and comparing 2 functions in chrome console.

[image]

In general, define the eventListener function in your class and attach it in `componentDidMount` and remove it in `componentWillUnmount`. Since they are executed once, the function reference remains same.

```js
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
 ...
 myEventFun = (e) => {console.log("Hello")};

 componentDidMount() {

    window.addEventListener("scroll", this.myEventFun);
  }

 componentWillUnmount() {
    window.removeEventListener("scroll", this.myEventFun);
  }
...
```

If you want to deal with adding/removing event listeners in functional component, [see this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55262596/using-useeffect-with-event-listeners) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55565444/how-to-register-event-with-useeffect-hooks)

Comment: hi - hope the answer was useful... do you have any follow up question on this.?